# Compiling a dictionary by pulling data from other dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing a project in which I extract data from three different data sets and combine it to look at campaign contributions. To do this I turned the relevant data from two of the sets into dictionaries (canDict and otherDict) with ID numbers as keys and the information I need (party affiliation) as values. Then I wrote a program to pull party information based on the key (my third set included these ID numbers as well) and match them with the employer of the donating party, and the amount donated. That was a long winded explanation, but I thought it would help with understanding this chunk of code.

My problem is that, for some reason, my third dictionary (employerDict) won't compile. By the end of this step I should have a dictionary containing employers as keys, and a list of tuples as values, but after running it, the dictionary remains blank. I've been over this line by line a dozen times and I'm pulling my hair out - I can't for the life of me think why it won't work, which is making it hard to search for answers. I've commented almost every line to try to make it easier to understand out of context. ***Can anyone spot my mistake?***

*Update:* I added a counter, n, to the outermost for loop to see if the program was iterating at all.

*Update 2:* I added another if statement in the creation of the variable `party`, in case the ID at data[0] did not exist in canDict or in otherDict. I also added some already suggested fixes from the comments.

```
n=0
with open(path3) as f:                         # path3 is a txt file
    for line in f:
        n+=1
        if n % 10000 == 0:
            print(n)
        data = line.split("|")                 # Splitting each line into its entries (delimited by the symbol |)
        party = canDict.get(data[0])           # data[0] is an ID number. canDict and otherDict contain these IDs as keys with party affiliations as values
        if party is None:
            party = otherDict[data[0]]         # If there is no matching ID number in canDict, search otherDict
            if party is None:
                party = 'Other'
        else:
            print('ERROR: party is None')
        x = (party, int(data[14]))             # Creating a tuple of the the party (found through the loop) and an integer amount from the file path3
        employer = data[11]                    # Index 11 in path3 is the employer of the person
        if employer != '':
            value = employerDict.get(employer) # If the employer field is not blank, see if this employer is already a key in employerDict
            if value is None:
                employerDict[employer] = [x]   # If the key does not exist, create it and add a list including the tuple x as its value
            else:
                employerDict[employer].append(x) # If it does exist, add the tuple x to the existing value
        else:
            print('ERROR: employer == ''')
```

Comment: My gut instinct is `employer != ''` is always evaluating to false. Try `print(employer != '')` before the second if statement.

Comment: In your 5th line, `data[0]` has no reason to be `None` (comes from `split`) .  So your 5th line should probably be `if party is None:`.

Comment: @AndrewJenkins Thanks for the idea but no luck :/ I also added a counter just to see if it was iterating at all (see update) and that is also returning an output of zero

Comment: @SciProg Just tried your fix, still no luck... counter is still 0. The reason I wrote it that way is because     data[0] is from path3, not from canDict. What I was trying to get at was "if     data[0] is not a key in     canDict". Is there a more correct way to try that?

Comment: I would add `else` statements to the last `if` statement. You may not be capturing every possibility. For example, `else : print( "DEBUG: employer == ''", employer )`.

Comment: @bebop Still no change, thanks though

Comment: I didn't expect that to solve your problem, but you can look at your output to see why your flow control isn't working the way you expect it to.

Comment: @bebop Sorry I wasn't clear! The program is giving no output, as before. n still == 0, employerDict still == {}, and it doesn't print either of the error messages I added at your suggestion. Again, thanks

Comment: `if n/10000 % 0` is division by zero.  This code won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input everyone - however, it looks like its a problem with my data file, not a problem with the program. Dangit.